# Line breaks inside a div and textarea

Tags: jquery, html, return, textarea

I have a textarea and dynamically on keydown i wanna know if there are any line breaks or not.
I AM putting the value  of textarea on keyup inside a div.
But if someone gives a carriage return in textarea .
There are no line breaks in div.
How can i possibly get the breaks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More people need to know about this:

```
<div style="white-space:pre-wrap">


                            SPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACE!

</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FdG4v/)

Comment: Of all the solutions, this was the only one that worked for me. You saved my day!!